# Create Relation between the database tables in Shopware 5

Tags: php, mysql, export, shopware, shopware5

For the variant product configuration i have created free text field for color code and varient images

**Path:** Configuration->Free text field management 
**Table selected:** configurator option (s_article_configurator_options_attributes)

[image: Free Text Field Management]

With the help of this free text field i have assigned the variant code and images in respective variant products

**Path:** In Item details->varients tab->configuration->active group selected->edit to active options

[image: Edit Option]

And displayed in the frontend something like this,

[image: Vatiants]

I see there's no option to export these details with SKU.

And to export the varient configurator images i'm tring to create a relation between the below database tables,
and get the varient images and code or option name with respective product **SKU**

- s_articles_details
- s_article_configurator_option_relations
- s_article_configurator_groups
- s_article_configurator_options
- s_media